# Go to specific character sequence if on line programmatically

Tags: search, motion

Is there a function that checks if a specific character sequence - "abc" - is on a line and puts point there if it is? And returning something (presumably nil) if "abc" isn't on the current line?

Comment: `isearch`?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Incremental-Search.html  See also the function `search-forward` and `re-search-forward` -- type `M-x describe-function` or `C-h f` to read the doc-strings -- both functions have the ability to set bounds/limits; e.g,. `line-ending-position`

Answer (score 1):

No, but it's easy to write one (guaranteed 100% untested):

```
(defun search-like-alex-seems-to-want (regexp)
  (let ((pos (save-excursion
               (forward-line 0) ;; Go to BOL.
               (re-search-forward regexp (line-end-position) t))))
    (when pos (goto-char pos))
    pos))
```